# How to add number of new html elements based on the number entered into ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular.  I am trying to add icons/input tags based on value entered into the model.

e.g. i have a model seat

```
  <input ng-model ="seat" >  //lets say user enters 3
```

i want to dynamically generate three models as

```
<input ng-model="seat.seat1">
<input ng-model="seat.seat2">
<input ng-model="seat.seat2">
```

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2):

Initial `$scope.seats` in Controller:

```
$scope.seats = [];
```

And add below code to Template:

```
<input ng-model="seats.length">
<input ng-repeat="seat in seats track by $index" ng-model="seats[$index]">
```

when change the `seats.length` to `3`, it will add null to array temporarily.

```
$scope.seats // [null, null, null]
```

So must to use `track by $index` to avoid same value issue

[Demo on plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lSp18f?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Chen-Tus Lin .. its working but one problem is there that the model name are not getting updated ..if i put 2 it generates two input tags with same model name which is  "seats[$index]"

Comment: `$index` is a variable that stores it's order in `ng-repeat` . model name will be set as seats[0], seats[1], seats[2] ..and so on by `ng-repeat`.

Comment: yes it should come but i observed in the inspector its showing  seats[$index] as a model name for all input tags

Comment: Angular will not directly compile $index to a number show on HTML inspector, but in the `ng-repeat's` scope $index will be the DOM order number.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-repeat and repeat the loop till the model value and inside that create the models.